# The return value of "putIfAbsent" must be used - really?

Tags: java, sonarqube

i've got a ConcurrentMap of ConcurrentMaps like this...

```
ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<K, V>> mapsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Now in some method, I would like to prevent NPE by making sure a map exists for a certain key like this...

```
 mapsMap.putIfAbsent(someKey, new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>());
```

...so I can safely call stuff like...

```
 mapsMap.get(someKey).put(...);
```

...without worrying about null values here.

Now, Sonarqube is telling me, that this violates the rule [RSPEC-2201](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2201)...

> Return values from functions without side effects should not be ignored
>   [..] and also on ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent calls ignored return value.

Is this just SonarQube not detecting that the side effect of the method is enough for me here (and the return value would not add any information) or am I missing an important point about the putIfAbsent contract?

Comment: It might well be SonarQube fault, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) doesn't mention anything similar.

Comment: Do this `mapsMap.putIfAbsent(someKey, new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>()).put(aValue)` if the two last snippets follow each other in your example

Comment: @Lino I prefer not to introduce NPEs into my code, if possible ;-) putIfAbsent returns `null`, if there was no value associated with that key before (because it returns the old value and not the new value).

Comment: I do wonder what they were wondering. It's also strange that they only do this for ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent -- not Map.putIfAbsent, which has the same contract.

Comment: @yshavit Agreed. It has probably a relation with concurrency. But which one ? :)

Comment: @davidxxx It doesn't make any sense to me, so it's hard to tell. :-) It's also odd because their docs say RSPEC-2201 is about "functions without side effects," and put definitely has a side effect. I could be overlooking something, but I actually suspect that this is just a broken rule in this aspect.

Comment: @yshavit Agreed. You could overlook something but you could do that with other methods of Map as `put()` and it will not explain why this method specifically.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz I think that you should wait for Sonar team answer or contact them directly if you don't want to mark that as a false positive.

Comment: Thanks, @davidxxx, I can mark it as false positive, no problem, I just feared that I would be wrong here with that and miss a concurrency bug or something similar. Will probably wait for an "official" answer or contact them directly otherwise.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz   Makes sense and your intention is good : it could very probably help others if we have a answer from them.

Comment: Got an answer there, which does not basically change what we already assumed (my code is safe), but explains the reasons behind the whole thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
>   mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns null,
>   else returns the current value.

You can safely ignore the returned value, if you don't need it.
`Sonarqube` is pretty invasive with certain rules, so just disable it and go on with your business.

Imho, that specific rule is mostly set for common patterns on a project where code is written by multiple developers.

Comment: My concern is, that it seems to be awfully specific to explicitly use the rule for `ConcurrentMap`, so I fear for some "hidden" reason here. Unfortunately I do not want to disable the rule, since for many other instances it totally makes sense, for example, the calling `"someString".toUpperCase()` without caring about the result is very likely a bug. On the part about the `ConcurrentMap` is unclear (or even wrong?).

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I meant disabling it for that specific case, which doesn't make sense to me. Honestly there is no hidden reason that I know of. You're just working with a synchronized implementation of the Map interface, but the produced result is the same as every other implementation which respect the Map contract.

Comment: Agreed for the first part but what do you mean by "Imho, that specific rule is mostly set for common patterns on a project where code is written by multiple developers." ? The number of developers working on a project doesn't have consequence on potential bug/issue at runtime.

Comment: @davidxxx Many Sonarqube rules are there to set coding standards for developers. Sometimes those rules are okay, sometimes not. The rule per se is okay, but this usecase if flawed

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct anser by @LppEdd, this question was also [answered](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/the-return-value-of-putifabsent-must-be-used-really/7335) over at the sonarqube forums:

Basically, this rule was taken from FindBugs' rule [RV_RETURN_VALUE_OF_PUTIFABSENT_IGNORED](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_OF_PUTIFABSENT_IGNORED)

> The putIfAbsent method is typically used to ensure that a single value
>   is associated with a given key (the first value for which put if
>   absent succeeds). If you ignore the return value and retain a
>   reference to the value passed in, you run the risk of retaining a
>   value that is not the one that is associated with the key in the map.
>   If it matters which one you use and you use the one that isn't stored
>   in the map, your program will behave incorrectly.

As in this case, I do not retain a reference to the value stored, this would indeed be a false positive.

It is likely that this specific rule will be implemented as a seperate rule in SonarQube in the future and not as part of the current rule (RSPEC-2201) anymore.